# using npm libraries in tabris-js app

Tags: node.js, npm, mqtt, tabris-js

I am new to programming and started with tabris-js mobile app development framework for pure javascript.
Tabris-js supports using npm modules an cordova plugins to extend.

I tried to import mqtt-js npm library into tabris-js app. 
Locally installed the library to path; 
project_folder/node_modules/mqtt/mqtt.js and added dependency in package.json.

When importing the module:

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
```

The error is: `could not parse the module .../mqtt.js`

Isn't mqtt-js compatible with tabris-js or is this a global issue?

Comment: Have you installed like - npm install mqtt

Comment: Yes I did - npm install mqtt - in project_folder. And I see the module -
 project_folder/node_modules/mqtt/mqtt.js - and also dependency added in package.json itself. I tried to run my app both in Tabris.js 2 developer app and build app. This is a module parse error not module find error really i don't know the difference so.

Comment: Try running your script through Node to see if you have the same problem.  For example, if the `main` entry in `package.json` is `app.js` then run `node app.js` from the command line.  If it's the same issue, then it's a problem with mqtt.

Comment: Cookie Guru I am trying right now and yes it is working ! - node app.js - is working. I got my message echoed from online public broker. So what am I doing wrong in my tabris app?

Comment: @Tragedart probably as Tim Buschtöns [suggested on Slack](https://tabrisjs.slack.com/archives/C0AQ5BK36/p1510662128000219)

Answer (score 0):

From the document;
MQTT.js is a client library for the MQTT protocol, written in JavaScript for node.js and the browser.
To use MQTT.js in the browser see the [browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#browserify) section.

I tested in the same way and this worked well. 
Browserified node_modules/mqtt/mqtt.js module to a browsermqtt.js and required this bundle into my tabris-js app.
And use MQTT over Websockets port to the broker.